# Conditional Logic for Salesforce Web-to-Lead form

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, conditional-statements, salesforce

I'm trying to create conditional logic for if/then situations. I would appreciate help with the html and the JavaScript, as I have little knowledge. However, I know enough to apply the same logic to other questions.

The example here shall be: If the project is confidential (Yes), then the field Confidential Project Name will appear and text will be required.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Is this project confidential?:<select id="00Nr0000000LC1Y" title="Is this project confidential?" name="00Nr0000000LC1Y" required="required">
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>

Confidential Project Name:<input id="00Nr0000000LC1d" maxlength="100" name="00Nr0000000LC1d" size="20" type="text" Required /><br>
```

Comment: have u any other js code running on the website? because there are many js frameworks out there which makes thinks really easy - I as an example prefer jQuery.
But for sure u can achieve this also in pure JS.

Comment: I use divi by elegant themes, and they have a code module that can be placed in the very same page. One code module would contain the html, and a second code module would contain the JavaScript. I suppose that is where I'd place the jQuery?  (hope that answer helped ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

check this out - thats pure JS:

```
Is this project confidential?:<select id="00Nr0000000LC1Y" title="Is this project confidential?" name="00Nr0000000LC1Y" required="required">
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>

<p id="pn" style="display: none;">Confidential Project Name:<input id="00Nr0000000LC1d" maxlength="100" name="00Nr0000000LC1d" size="20" type="text" Required /><p>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('00Nr0000000LC1Y');
el.addEventListener("change", function(){
 var pn = document.getElementById('pn');
 if (this.value == "Yes"){
   pn.style.display='inherit';
 } else {
   pn.style.display='none';
 }
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9v8e6q4h/

Comment: Actually, one thing is not working. When No is selected, the form won't let you submit... probably because the form is requiring that hidden field to be filled. Once I marked yes and filled it, it let me submit form. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to the "hidden field is still required" problem. I found something similar to the code above, yet different... I wonder how this can be applied to the above? `container.change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'manual') {
    container.addClass('visible');
    if (requiredInputs) {
      requiredInputs.prop('required', 'true');
    }
  } else {
    container.removeClass('visible');
    if (requiredInputs) {
      requiredInputs.prop('required', 'false');
    }
  }
});`